# Can I expose a user's FCM token to other users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

The documentation says a device's token should be kept secret. However, I've read here that the token itself doesn't do much. And that no one else can send messages to my app without my API key.

I want to allow communication between two users. One user completes some action, then send an FCM message to inform the other user's app. For this, it seems simpler to have them share their tokens across a cloud function like so, but I cannot find an example of someone doing the same.

```
const message  = {
               token: token,
               data:{
                 token : myToken,
                 task: task,                 
                 authID: authID 
          }};
```

What is the harm in sharing these tokens like so?

I don't plan to send sensitive data. The FCM message, is primarily to prompt a user when to access a firestore document. A document which has it's own security rules.

Comment: There is nothing inherently dangerous about sharing the FCM token. See the linked questions for more on this.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you! I wanted to double check since all the examples I could find would store the token in a database then read it each time they wanted to send a message to a device.